# Position an element to a bottom of a div using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to position an button element at the bottom of a div using flex, but currently I did not find any solution.

Let me imagine:

[image]

I want to position the `button` at the bottom of the whole div.
Actual styles:

```
.blackSquareContainer{
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 490px;
}
```

I tried on `button` styles: `margin-top: 0` but it displays the button on the right side of `blackSquareContainer`. I also tried `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` - it also did not help.

I need also to add, that clicking on button add some rows to div below `blackSquareContainer`. Unfortunately even if I add this button in that place if I click on it, the div below grow and overlap it. `min-height` also dont help ;/

What should I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin-top: auto` on `button` with `flex-direction: column` on container.

```css
.blackSquareContainer{
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackSquareContainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working for me, see what i add in my question

Comment: oh, god, the parent container had got lower min-height than `blackSquareContainer` , yeah it works now. Ty for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To justify flex children from the bottom of the container, use `justify-content: flex-end`;

```
.blackSquareContainer{
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 490px;
}
```